# Pass checked checkboxes to controller through ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a project on ASP.net MVC.

I have a html form with some checkboxes say A,B,C,D & E and
I am posting the form through ajax to one of the controllers.

I would like to distinctly identify if each check boxes are checked from the controller and perform some action based on the selected checkbox value.

I would like to know the **best practise** to acheive this.

P.S: I will be passing the selected checkbox value to the underlying DAL.

Comment: I think this question needs to be  developing a project || POC

Comment: You can send value from controller to view using ViewBag and on view check whether the ViewBag is null or not and perform what ever you want.

Comment: some links would be of great help @ Ramesh Rajendran

Comment: @monu: Can you please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: See this sample : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907004/get-checkbox-values-in-controller-mvc-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in many ways. Here i'm giving a sample idea-

**Using a model object**

Lets assume, you have a model "CheckBoxValues" in server side with the fields

```
public class CheckBoxValues
{
    public Boolean A { get; set; }
    public Boolean B { get; set; }
}
```

On your html page, use the code to get values from the checkboxes on a button click handler-

```
var values= {};
var StateOfCheckBoxA = $('#CheckBoxA').is(':checked'); 
values.A= StateOfCheckBoxA  ;
var StateOfCheckBoxB = $('#CheckBoxB').is(':checked'); 
values.B= StateOfCheckBoxB;

var SubmitURL = YourController/ActionMethod/


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: SubmitURL,
                data: values,
                dataType: 'json',

                beforeSend: function () {

                },
                success: function (result) {

                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {

                },
                complete: function () {

                }
            });
```

Now your actionmethod

```
 public JsonResult Create(CheckBoxValues values)
 {
       Boolean checkboxA=values.A;
       Boolean checkboxB=values.B;
 }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.I would like to have a method without using the CheckBoxValues model. May be only ant integer value being passed from form to controller. Beacause my Logic Layer is a seperate project and i cannot use this model there.

Comment: you can use the code above, just change the ajax type to "GET" and add a Query String to the url , additionally you should a add a server side code to deal with this new information.

Comment: @Shanky, you can send an array of integer in the same way without using any model.